# Rails cache counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I have a simple Ruby method meant to throttle some execution.

```
MAX_REQUESTS = 60
# per
TIME_WINDOW = 1.minute

def throttle
  cache_key = "#{request.ip}_count"
  count = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: TIME_WINDOW.to_i) { 0 }

  if count.to_i >= MAX_REQUESTS
    render json: { message: 'Too many requests.' }, status: 429
    return
  end
  Rails.cache.increment(cache_key)
  true
end
```

After some testing I've found that `cache_key` never invalidates.

I investigated with `binding.pry` and found the issue:

```
[35] pry(#<Refinery::ApiReferences::Admin::ApiHostsController>)> Rails.cache.write(cache_key, count += 1, expires_in: 60, raw: true)
=> true
[36] pry(#<Refinery::ApiReferences::Admin::ApiHostsController>)> Rails.cache.send(:read_entry, cache_key, {})
=> #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Entry:0x007fff1e34c978 @created_at=1495736935.0091069, @expires_in=60.0, @value=11>
[37] pry(#<Refinery::ApiReferences::Admin::ApiHostsController>)> Rails.cache.increment(cache_key)
=> 12
[38] pry(#<Refinery::ApiReferences::Admin::ApiHostsController>)> Rails.cache.send(:read_entry, cache_key, {})
=> #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Entry:0x007fff1ee105a8 @created_at=1495736965.540865, @expires_in=nil, @value=12>
```

So, `increment` is wiping out the `expires_in` value and changing the `created_at`, regular writes will do the same thing.

How do I prevent this? I just want to update the *value* for a given cache key.

**UPDATE**

Per suggestion I tried:

```
MAX_REQUESTS = 60
# per
TIME_WINDOW = 1.minute

def throttle
  cache_key = "#{request.ip}_count"
  count = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: TIME_WINDOW.to_i, raw: true) { 0 }

  if count.to_i >= MAX_REQUESTS
    render json: { message: 'Too many requests.' }, status: 429
    return
  end
  Rails.cache.increment(cache_key)
  true
end
```

No effect. Cache does not expire.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "solution," I won't mark it correct because surely this isn't necessary?

```
MAX_REQUESTS = 60
# per
TIME_WINDOW = 1.minute

def throttle
  count_cache_key = "#{request.ip}_count"
  window_cache_key = "#{request.ip}_window"

  window = Rails.cache.fetch(window_cache_key) { (Time.zone.now + TIME_WINDOW).to_i }

  if Time.zone.now.to_i >= window
    Rails.cache.write(window_cache_key, (Time.zone.now + TIME_WINDOW).to_i)
    Rails.cache.write(count_cache_key, 1)
  end

  count = Rails.cache.read(count_cache_key) || 0

  if count.to_i >= MAX_REQUESTS
    render json: { message: 'Too many requests.' }, status: 429
    return
  end

  Rails.cache.write(count_cache_key, count + 1)
  true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing a ***raw* value** (with `raw: true` option) in Rails cache works exactly the way you desire, i.e. it **updates only the value**, not the expiration time. However, when debugging this, you cannot rely on the output of `read_entry` very much as this does not correspond fully with the raw value stored in cache, because the cache store does not give back the expiry time when storing just the raw value.

That is why, normally (without the `raw`) option, Rails does not store just the raw value, but it creates a [cache Entry object](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L632) which, besides the value, holds additional data, such as the expiry time. Then it serializes this object and saves it to the cache store. Upon reading the value back, it de-serializes the object and still has access to all info, including the expiry time.

However, as you cannot increment a serialized object, you need to store a *raw value* instead, i.e. use the `raw: true` option. This makes Rails store directly the value and pass the expiry time as param to the cache store `write` method (without the possibility to read it back from the store).

So, to sum up, you must use `raw: true` when caching a value for incrementing and the expiry time will be normally preserved in the cache store. See the following test (done on the `mem_cache_store` store):

```
# cache_test.rb
cache_key = "key"

puts "setting..."
Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: 3.seconds, raw: true) { 1 }
puts "#{Time.now} cached value: #{Rails.cache.read(cache_key)}"

sleep(2)
puts "#{Time.now} still cached: #{Rails.cache.read(cache_key)}"

puts "#{Time.now} incrementing..."
Rails.cache.increment(cache_key)
puts "#{Time.now} incremented value: #{Rails.cache.read(cache_key)}"

sleep(1)
puts "#{Time.now} gone!: #{Rails.cache.read(cache_key).inspect}"
```

When running this, you'll get:

```
$ rails runner cache_test.rb 
Running via Spring preloader in process 31666
setting...
2017-05-25 22:15:26 +0200 cached value: 1
2017-05-25 22:15:28 +0200 still cached: 1
2017-05-25 22:15:28 +0200 incrementing...
2017-05-25 22:15:28 +0200 incremented value: 2
2017-05-25 22:15:29 +0200 gone!: nil
```

As you can see, the value has been incremented without resetting the expiry time.

**Update:** I set up a minimal test for you code, though not run through a real controller but only as a script. I made only 4 small changes to the `throttle` code in your OP:

1. lowered the time window
2. changed `render` to a simple `puts`
3. used only a single key as if requests came from a single IP address
4. print the incremented value

The script:

```
# chache_test2.rb
MAX_REQUESTS = 60
# per
#TIME_WINDOW = 1.minute
TIME_WINDOW = 3.seconds

def throttle
  #cache_key = "#{request.ip}_count"
  cache_key = "127.0.0.1_count"
  count = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: TIME_WINDOW.to_i, raw: true) { 0 }

  if count.to_i >= MAX_REQUESTS
    #render json: { message: 'Too many requests.' }, status: 429
    puts "too many requests"
    return
  end

  puts Rails.cache.increment(cache_key)
  true
end

62.times do |i|
  throttle
end

sleep(3)
throttle
```

The run prints the following:

```
$ rails runner cache_test2.rb 
Running via Spring preloader in process 32589
2017-05-26 06:11:26 +0200 1
2017-05-26 06:11:26 +0200 2
2017-05-26 06:11:26 +0200 3
2017-05-26 06:11:26 +0200 4
...
2017-05-26 06:11:26 +0200 58
2017-05-26 06:11:26 +0200 59
2017-05-26 06:11:26 +0200 60
2017-05-26 06:11:26 +0200 too many requests
2017-05-26 06:11:26 +0200 too many requests
2017-05-26 06:11:29 +0200 1
```

Perhaps you don't have caching configured in development at all? I recommend testing this in the memcached store, which is the most preferred cache store in production environment. In development, you need to explicitly switch it on:

```
# config/environemnts/development.rb
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
```

Also, if you are running a recent Rails 5.x version, you may need to run the `rails dev:cache` command [which creates](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/25/caching-in-development-environment-in-rails5.html) the `tmp/caching-dev.txt` file that is used in the development config to actually enable caching in development env.

Comment: thanks for the response! Tried it (see above) didn't work. Did I miss something?

Comment: It works for me, see updated answer. Did you try the trivial test above? What cache store are you using? It might not work the same way on all cache stores. I test all this on memcached using the Dalli gem.

Comment: Huh, tried the code you provided, ran it under my project's rails runner, same problem, "too many requests" forever after 60. I've determined my `cache_store` is `:memory_store`. Next, I'll try to get `dalli` and `:mem_cache_store` set up on my project. (Rails 4.2.7.1 for reference.)